# Showing finer values on the x-axis using plot()

Tags: r, plot

I have two vectors: x and y. I'm plotting them with plot(x,y, type="l"). However I want to show the detailed values on the x-axis between the plotted values on the x-axis. Now I have 0 ... 20 ... 40 ... I want to show 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 20 and I want them to be in smaller size than the main values. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you investigated using `axis` yet? You should do that, make an attempt, and then report back on any trouble you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your question

```
grid = 1:100

x = rnorm(100)
plot(x,type='l')
axis(1,grid[c(-20,-40,-60,-80,-100)],grid[c(-20,-40,-60,-80,-100)],cex.axis=.5,line=-1,tick=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the quality of the image.  Had to convert pdf to jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Use `axis` to customize it. For example:

```
plot(seq(1,100,10), rnorm(10),type='l',cex.axis=2,
     lwd.ticks=5)
axis(1, 1:100[-c(20,40,60,80,100)],
     1:100[-c(20,40,60,80,100)],tick=TRUE,
     cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: the thick values are covering the small values, how to solve this?